# Where is the scene model file in the vision pro simulator?

Tags: visionos, visionos-simulator

There are 6 scenes to choose from in the Vision Pro simulator. I am curious where these files are placed? Can it be replaced or added?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found them. I haven't tried to modify them, remove them, or add to them.

In `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes` you'll find a folder for each runtime you've installed on your machine. `xrOS_21N305` is visionOS 1.0. `xrOS_21O209` is visionOS 1.1.

Inside each of those, environments are found in:

- `Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/xrOS\ 1.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Assets/SystemEnvironments` (for 1.0)
- `Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/xrOS\ 1.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Assets/SystemEnvironments` (for 1.1)

Within the `SystemEnvironments` folder you'll find 6 environments (kitchen, living room, museum, day and night). Within each environment is an `AssetData` folder, which contains a `.usdc` file.

So 1.1's night kitchen is at
`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/xrOS_21O209/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/xrOS\ 1.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Assets/SystemEnvironments/SyntheticEnvironments/KitchenNight/AssetData/kitchen_dining_night.usdc`.

The full command to show all 12:

`ls /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/xrOS_*/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/xrOS\ */Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Assets/SystemEnvironments/SyntheticEnvironments/*/AssetData/*usdc`

Comment: Great job, Hal. +1 from me.